# Directory vs. Folder

Tags: filesystems

Are both names synonyms or should one prefer one name over the other on different platforms?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

As seen in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/187900/what-is-the-difference-between-a-directory-and-a-folder), they are **not** the same.

[Authoritative answer given by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110216-00/?p=11473):

> Windows 95 introduced Windows Explorer
> and along with it the term folder.
> What is the relationship between
> folders and directories?
>
> Some people believe that Windows 95
> renamed directories to folders, but
> it's actually more than that.
>
> Windows Explorer lets you view
> folders, which are containers in the
> shell namespace. Directories are one
> type of folder, namely, folders which
> correspond to file system locations.
> There are other types of folders, such
> as Control Panel or Network
> Neighborhood or Printers. These other
> types of folders represent objects in
> the shell namespace which do not
> correspond to files. In common usage,
> the term virtual folder has been
> applied to refer to folders which are
> not directories. In other words, we
> have this Euler diagram:
>
> [image] (Virtual folders = Folders −
> Directories)
>
> In general, code which manipulates the
> shell namespace should operate on
> folders and items, not directories and
> files, so as not to tie themselves to
> a particular storage medium. For
> example, code which limits itself to
> files won't be able to navigate into a
> Zip file, since the contents of a Zip
> file are exposed in the form of a
> virtual folder.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1195096/412486

Comment: Are you able to incorporate Virtual Folders into that diagram? maybe like http://i.imgur.com/PCbhJfu.png

Comment: Microsoft was always wrong with this design because it denies clean, easy access to virtual folders and other resources via Command Prompt - something we still can't do today.  Can you navigate a ZIP file from Command Prompt or Powershell like a normal directory?  No?  But Explorer can.  Of course, doing so would require rethinking obsolete things like drive letters too, which itself has held back Windows development for at least a couple of decades.  The correct approach for OS design was and still is:  Command-line first, GUI second.

Answer (score 23):

As a reference to physical locations on the hard drive they are synonyms.

Windows tends to use "Folder".

*nix tends to use "Directory".

On Windows you have virtual folders (as mentioned in malfruct's answer) which are represented as directories but can be actually stored as files (zip files for example).

However, to the end user this distinction doesn't usually matter.

Comment: Virtual folders can reach beyond the files concept. For example Control Panel or libraries (Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos) or Devices and Printers – they are not "actually stored as files", although their content is sometimes (not always) constructed using files and referring to them.

Answer (score 15):

@mafu quotes Raymond Chen as writing:

> Windows 95 introduced Windows Explorer and along with it the term folder.

Raymond Chan is rewriting history.

In fact, Microsoft Windows 95 borrowed many UI design ideas from Apple.  And Apple in turn borrowed them from Xerox.  Both the name "folder" and the visual metaphor of folders were part of the Xerox Star office environment in 1982<sup>1</sup>.

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)#Folder_metaphor

---

<sup>1 - In 1985, I used a DLion workstation running Xerox software to write my PhD thesis ... if you want a source for that fact.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. The question is about the difference between the terms folder and directory. Chen makes it clear that on Windows, the difference is such and such, and your wikipedia link states the concept pretty similarly.

Comment: In his first sentence, Chen appears to state that Microsoft introduced the term "folder".  This is false.  That is my point.

Comment: Well, Chen's stating the fact that that term was introduced to be used in Windows, which is undeniable. He's not (clearly) saying that that was the first time the term was ever used. It also does not really matter who invented it, as long as the difference between both terms are similar, and that they are, according to what you linked to. (And even if it were different on Xerox - that would merely be a historical note with no relevance in 2017.)

Comment: If he is stating that, then his language is clumsy.  Because that is NOT how it reads / parses.  Either way, (if he is deliberately rewriting history, if he is unaware of the precedents, or if his writing is clumsy) it detracts from his "authority".  You say "clearly".  I disagree.

Comment: Or maybe the fault is with you for calling this an authoritative source.  It is arguably authoritative for Windows, but it is not authoritative in the context of the question .... which is about **different platforms**.

Comment: The position of 'clearly' in my sentence was intentional; I did not say "he's clearly not saying x" but "he's not clearly saying x". Apart from that, this is way too much which hunting for me, I don't think he or I ever intended to rewrite history. His answer is what one would call authoritative on the platform used by the overwhelming majority of people for 2 decades (and thus likely what the asker wanted to know, as this is not tagged *history*), **and** it identically applies to other platforms, too. You're getting all heated up over an unimportant language ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx), you can read :

> In Windows, the terms "directory" and "folder" are used
>   interchangeably. Most documentation and user interface text uses the
>   term "folder," but the .NET Framework class library uses the term
>   "directory."

So I think that both are fine. I tend to use "folder" as it's shorter and I'm lazy.

Comment: Thanks. This MSDN reference is the most useful thing I've found on this question.

Answer (score 2):

For GUI platforms, "Folder" name is recommended where as for command line environment, "Directory" name is suited.

Comment: Is recommended, by whom?

Comment: Citation needed

Answer (score 1):

What humanfly said, with the additional note that some programs use "Folder" but NEVER directory, i.e. in email programs like Outlook.  You never have "subdirectories" but  you often have "subfolders".

Comment: Does Outlook really work with file system directories? Or does it offer just virtual e-mail folders?

Comment: No, it's only folders.  I was making a point that the terminology is NOT always interchangeable.  You didn't specify for just system tree structure in your question.

Comment: The term subdirectory does exist, and means much the same as subfolder in this context.