# In HKCR, what is difference between Directory and Folder in context menu config

Tags: windows-xp, shell-extensions

Following up on this question over at SO ([How do I open cmd window in specific location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904/how-can-i-open-a-cmd-window-in-a-specific-location)) I'm looking for an effective way to add the Open Command Prompt Here shortcut to a context menu. Various solutions propose adding entries to HKCR\Folder and others suggest adding entries to HKCR\Directory.

Based on this question ([Directory Vs. Folder](https://superuser.com/questions/169457/directory-vs-folder)) it seems a folder could be virtual or not while a directory is always "real". A ven diagram would have folder being a large circle and directory a smaller circle completely enclosed within the folder circle.

For the sake of a command prompt, is it correct to assume I'll probably only be dealing with "real" folders, or directories?

The questions then are as follows:
Can I open a command prompt window in a virtual directory and what conceivable reason would I have for doing this?
Would adding a context menu item ONLY to HKCR\Folder cover all my bases and then some?
Would adding a context menu item ONLY to HKCR\Directory end up missing some things?

Finally, for brownie points:
What if I wanted to be able to add an entry to open a command prompt by clicking inside a folder rather than on a folder icon, which context menu item would I have to use to get this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I did it was add the Open command prompt to **all objects**.  The open command prompt passes the working directory (cmd /k pushd %d") and you get the command prompt on the working directory of the object you right clicked.

For the most part, you CAN open a command prompt in a virtual folder. It depends though.  For example, DFS folders return a command prompt at a UNC.  But trying to get a command prompt on an object in a search folder just gets you the real location of the object.

Edit:

To get the command prompt when you right click the background requires that you write a shell extension.  And since Microsoft **insists** shell extensions be written in native code !me :(   See the MSDN on the shell extension menu.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067(v=vs.85).aspx

Or you could just download this program: Context Console Shell Extension.

http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/

Comment: So does this mean adding a command prompt to each object entry in HKCR? Or is there a global object? I've loaded the Context Console app and will be testing it today. However, the geek in me wants to know more.

Comment: @music2myear: There's a `*` entry under HKCR.

Comment: @surfasb: There's a very, **very** good reason that MS insists on native code for shell extensions - a process can only host a single instance of the .NET framework.  What do you think happens if you try to load 3 shell exts, each requiring a different revision of the .NET FW (e.g., 1.1, 3.0, and 4.0)?  *Things break.*

Comment: It's an unfortunate (or **fortunate** depending on who you are) reality.  I first learned to code in C++ but quickly realized I would never excel at it.  Probably would of done more harm than good. So it's managed code for this lifetime.

Comment: @music2myear: I suggest you read the link and all the links under the Shell extension section.  If that is too much effort, just download the Shell extension. . .

Comment: Yea, I'm performing an internal cost/benefit analysis on that. I tend to follow rabbit trails with relish, and this looks as though it may lead to a doozy. I'm deciding if it is worth spending time figuring this out when the reason I came to this question was to make it easier to follow a C# tutorial. I've installed the extension and it's working very well, doing exactly what I want. Thank you both for your input, I think this one's been answered to my satisfaction and beyond.

Comment: Yeah, the extension is well written. The source code link is on the same page. BTW, I **did** read all those links and I can assure you, it is **not** worth it for a non-native coder.

Answer (score 1):

For your bonus question: There's no registry key you can modify that lets you do what you want. Install [ContextConsole](http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/) to get that functionality.  A shell extension is required in this instance because when you click on the background of a folder, you don't have any object selected.

For your other questions: You can CD to a virtual folder in the Command Prompt if it's backed by a real folder in the file system (e.g., `Fonts` or `Start Menu`). Purely virtual folders (e.g. `Control Panel`) have no filesystem path, so no way to CD to it.

PowerShell supports namespace extensions and allows for doing things like setting your location to a registry path:

```
PS C:\> Set-Location HKLM:\Software\Classes\Directory
PS HKLM:\Software\Classes\Directory> Get-ChildItem


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Directory


SKC  VC Name                           Property
---  -- ----                           --------
  2   0 Background                     {}
  0   1 DefaultIcon                    {(default)}
  2   1 shell                          {(default)}
  4   0 shellex                        {}
```

If you want to add reg keys to `HKCR\Directory`, add them to `HKCR\Drive` too if you need them to show up got the drive's root folder too.