# Reduced "New" context submenu in folders with a symlink to mapped network drive in path

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, symbolic-link, mapped-drive

I observe some strange behavior of Windows Explorer in folders having in path symlinks to a mapped network drive. Here's an example.

I have a network drive mapped to `G:` and a symlink `testing` pointing to a folder on that network drive:
[image: 1]

Here's the "New" context submenu that I have right after following the symlink:
[image: 2]

Looks ok. And here's the same submenu in the `mocking` subfolder:
[image: 3]

The options list is much shorter. For comparison, the same submenu in the same forlder reached directly:
[image: 4]

The "New" context submenu is cut off in the `mocking` folder when it's reached via symlink but it's ok in the same folder reached directly.

What's the cause? And how can I have the submenu not reduced after following a symlink?

Comment: I am not going to research this right now.. but why are you trying to use a mapped drive in the first place?  Mapped drives are just another layer of worthless and confuse many programs due to file system vs functionality.  You can create a symbolic link for directories using the share DIRECTLY.. like this `mklink /D D:\whatever_you_like \\network\share` .. I myself would try this method first and not worry about shortcomings of the explorer (pandora's box).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas in this case it doesn't matter whether the network share is symlinked directly or via network drive. Explorer behaves the same in both cases.

Comment: Fair enough Mr. vect.  I can tell you what is happening under the hood but not actually WHY (which is why I am not posting an answer).  It might help you resolve the problem yourself.  When you right click THAT folder, the explorers shell extension handler is determining that it isn't a directory, instead.. that it is a folder (aka, no file system, no clusters, etc).  [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/310671/in-hkcr-what-is-difference-between-directory-and-folder-in-context-menu-config) talks about it quite a bit.  I know not an answer but might be of some help.